# Why are there more entries in my LEFT JOIN table than in either source table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

**Goal**

Using SQLite, I want to create a new table based on the join of two existing tables:

Table 1 (`repository_exporter`) schema:

```
CREATE TABLE repository_exporter (
                id TEXT NOT NULL,
                fullPath TEXT NOT NULL,
                visibility TEXT NOT NULL,
                httpUrlToRepo TEXT NOT NULL,
                projectUniqueName TEXT NOT NULL,
                ownershipLevelDepth INT NOT NULL,
                ownershipLevel1 TEXT NOT NULL,
                ownershipLevel2 TEXT NOT NULL,
                ownershipLevel3 TEXT NOT NULL,
                ownershipLevel4 TEXT NOT NULL,
                ownershipLevel5 TEXT NOT NULL,
                ownershipLevel6 TEXT NOT NULL
            );
```

Table 2 (`t`) schema:

```
CREATE TABLE t        (
             Project       text   ,
             Language      text   ,
             File          text   ,
             File_dirname  text   ,
             File_basename text   ,
             nByte         integer,
             nBlank        integer,
             nComment      integer,
             nCode         integer,
             nComplexity   integer   );
```

The new table would consist of a selection of columns from both tables.
Every entry from Table `t` should join an entry from Table `repository_exporter`, but any entry from `repository_exporter` can be matched against multiple entries in `t`.

To demonstrate, see the example below:

`repository_exporter`:

| id | fullPath | httpUrlToRepo | ownershipLevel2 | ... | projectUniqueName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ../full/path | ... | owner1 | ... | project1 |
| 2 | ../full/path2 | ... | owner1 | ... | project2 |

`t`:

| Project | Language | File | nByte | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| project1 | Python | file.py | 100 | ... |
| project1 | HTML | file.html | 200 | ... |
| project2 | Python | file2.py | 150 | ... |

`analysis`:

| fullPath | httpUrlToRepo | ownershipLevel2 | projectUniqueName | Project | Language | File | nByte | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ../full/path | ... | owner1 | project1 | project1 | Python | file.py | 100 | ... |
| ../full/path | ... | owner1 | project1 | project1 | HTML | file.html | 200 | ... |
| ../full/path2 | ... | owner1 | project2 | project2 | Python | file2.py | 150 | ... |

**Attempt + Result**

The SQL command I used was:

```
CREATE TABLE 'analysis' AS 
  SELECT repository_exporter.fullPath, 
    repository_exporter.httpUrlToRepo, 
    repository_exporter.ownershipLevel2, 
    repository_exporter.projectUniqueName, 
    Project, Language, File, nByte, nBlank, 
    nComment, nCode, nComplexity 
  FROM t 
  LEFT JOIN repository_exporter 
    ON t.Project = repository_exporter.projectUniqueName;
```

However, when I run `SELECT COUNT() FROM analysis;`, it finds **1796887** entries in the new table. The number of entries in `t` is **1373748**, and in `repository_exporter` is **9547**. I would expect the number of entries in `analysis` to match the number of entries in `t`.

If it is relevant, there are likely duplicate entries in `repository_exporter.ownershipLevel2`, `t.Language`, `t.File`, `t.nByte`, `t.nBlank`, `t.nComment`, `t.nCode`, and `t.nComplexity`

Comment: Hi - what's stopping you looking at your data and working out why the counts are not what you are expecting? You say "there are likely duplicate entries..." - so can you confirm this is the case or not? As we don't have access to your data there's not a lot anyone can do to help you

Comment: Hi Nick. I have confirmed that there are duplicates in all the columns I mentioned, as well as in t.Project and repository_exporter.projectUniqueName. My main concern is the SQL command I used to build the new table - as an SQL newbie, its not clear to me where I could have introduced duplicates into the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must understand what [LEFT JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) does: it takes every record from the left table and add data ( according to the JOIN condition ) from the right table.

- If condition is not satisfied, the fields from the right table are left NULL.
- If there is one record in the right table that satisfies the JOIN condition, the data from it is provided to the result.
- If there are multiple records in the right table that satisfy the JOIN condition - the result contains as many records as there are records satisfying the condition: the data from left table record gets repeated in all of them.

Please notice, that only in the third situation you get more rows in the result, than there are in the left table.

This allows to conclude, that for some records of `t` there are several records in `repository_exporter` satisfying condition `t.Project = repository_exporter.projectUniqueName`. Seems the `projectUniqueName` is not unique in table `repository_exporter`.

You can check that using SQL:

```
SELECT 
  projectUniqueName, count(*) 
FROM 
  repository_exporter
GROUP BY 
  projectUniqueName
HAVING 
  count(*) > 1
```

Hope the explanation helps understanding the concept of LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Thank you Julius, your explanation is clear and you are correct in deducing that there are duplicates in projectUniqueName. I will have to look at how to further differentiate the duplicates.